# Android - OnClickListener - Constructor Not Being Called

Tags: java, android, constructor, onclick, onclicklistener

This is my first question.  Usually I can find my answers through Gogle which usually just brings me to stackoverflow anyways, but this finally pushed me far enough to ask my own question, probably so obvious nobody needed to ask it before!

Anyways, this isn't for anything in particular. Just trying to get a handle on `onlicklisteners`.  In this case, specifically inner-class `onclicklisteners`.

**Problem:** Why is the program skipping over the constructor for `MathButtonClicked`?
I was it a `CharSequence`, but the constructor never gets called (I know this via the logcat).

```
public class Main extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button mathButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mathButton);
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);
    CharSequence inputText = et.getText().toString();


    mathButton.setOnClickListener(new MathButtonClicked(inputText));
}

private class MathButtonClicked implements OnClickListener {
    private CharSequence receivedText;

    public MathButtonClicked(CharSequence inputText) {
        this.receivedText=inputText;
        Log.d("Constructor", " " + receivedText);
    }



    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d("Onclick", " " + receivedText);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Math.class);
        intent.putExtra("inputText", getText());
        startActivity(intent);          
    }

    public CharSequence getText(){
        return receivedText;
    }
    }//end inner class
} //end main
```

Aren't constructors always called if the arguments match the parameters? @_@

Also, what I'm trying to accomplish is pass the text in the `EditText` view to a new intent.

I can do this by creating the `EditText` object in the `OnClick`, but I want to create it in the main method and then pass the information to the `OnClick`.

Thanks!

Comment: how do you know it is skipping the constructor? Try setting a breakpoint instead of rely on Log.d

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Button mathButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mathButton);
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputText);
CharSequence inputText = et.getText().toString();



 mathButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                     String receivedText=inputText;
         Log.d("Onclick", " " + receivedText);
                     Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Math.class);
                     intent.putExtra("inputText", receivedText);
                     startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Comment: I guess my goal was to use a named inner class.  Is that possible?

Comment: Actually the way you write it, you can't refer to `inputText` in your `OnClickListener`. `inputText` shoud either be `final` or a class variable.

Comment: It all had to do with setting the EditText to final @_@;;  Thanks Benito for the inspiration